# Make shader independent from object's world position

Tags: unity, shaders

I am not sure if I titled the issue correctly, but I will describe in details:

I have a building as a single mesh, but with windows as separate faces whith individual materials. I want that windows to not just be simple texture, but with interior mapping shader.

I found [this one](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/vfx/shaders/fake-interiors-free-104029), and it works as I need, except one thing: it has rooms and "floors" tilling parameters, so one can set for a single surface a few fake windows, but in my case, because I already apply shader to the face that is a window, I do not need tilling.

So I set parameters the way, the shader started display it as a single, window, but I when I moved camera from the wall, I noticed, that another windows have different offsets. It seems like shader shares the world space, or something like this. But if I move the building, the windows do not change their "rooms", it stays the same. I do not understand how it works, and what is the dependecy.

[image]

I tried to fix it, but I do not pretty familiar with shaders codes, and, also, exactly this shader seems to me obfuscated at all (I am not sure)(not the whole code, but I think cut part is not usefull):

```
    // Made with Amplify Shader Editor
    // Available at the Unity Asset Store - http://u3d.as/y3X 
    Shader "ASESampleShaders/Fake Interiors FREE"
    {
        Properties
        {
            _RoomColorTint("Room Color Tint", Color) = (1,1,1,0)
            _RoomIntensity("Room Intensity", Range( 0 , 100)) = 1
            [Toggle]_FacadeTexture("Facade Texture", Int) = 0
            [NoScaleOffset]_FacadeAlbedo("Facade Albedo", 2D) = "black" {}
            _FacadeTiling("Facade Tiling", Range( 0.5 , 20)) = 0
            [NoScaleOffset]_FacadeSmoothness("Facade Smoothness", 2D) = "white" {}
            _SmoothnessValue("Smoothness Value", Range( 0 , 1)) = 1
            [NoScaleOffset]_Floor("Floor", 2D) = "white" {}
            _FloorTexTiling("Floor Tex Tiling", Range( 0 , 10)) = 0
            [NoScaleOffset]_Wall("Wall", 2D) = "white" {}
            _WalltexTiling("Wall tex Tiling", Range( 0 , 100)) = 0
            [Toggle]_TogglePropLayer("Toggle Prop Layer", Int) = 0
            [NoScaleOffset]_Props("Props", 2D) = "white" {}
            _PropsTexTiling("Props Tex Tiling", Range( 0 , 100)) = 0
            [NoScaleOffset]_Back("Back", 2D) = "white" {}
            _BackWallTexTiling("Back Wall Tex Tiling", Range( 0 , 100)) = 0
            [Toggle]_SwitchPlane("Switch Plane", Int) = 0
            [NoScaleOffset]_Ceiling("Ceiling", 2D) = "white" {}
            _CeilingTexTiling("Ceiling Tex Tiling", Range( 0 , 100)) = 0
            _RoomTile("Room Tile", Range( 0.1 , 10)) = 0
            _RoomsXYZPropsW("Rooms X Y Z , Props W", Vector) = (1,1,1,1)
            _PositionOffsetXYZroomsWprops("Position Offset, XYZ = rooms, W = props", Vector) = (0,0,0,0)
            [HideInInspector] _texcoord( "", 2D ) = "white" {}
            [HideInInspector] __dirty( "", Int ) = 1
        }

        SubShader
        {
            Tags{ "RenderType" = "Opaque"  "Queue" = "Geometry+0" "DisableBatching" = "True" }
            Cull Back
            CGPROGRAM
            #include "UnityShaderVariables.cginc"
            #pragma target 3.0
            #pragma shader_feature _SWITCHPLANE_ON
            #pragma shader_feature _TOGGLEPROPLAYER_ON
            #pragma shader_feature _FACADETEXTURE_ON
            #pragma surface surf Standard keepalpha addshadow fullforwardshadows vertex:vertexDataFunc 
            struct Input
            {
                float3 data447;
                float2 uv_texcoord;
            };

            uniform float4 _RoomColorTint;
            uniform float4 _RoomsXYZPropsW;
            uniform float _RoomTile;
            uniform float4 _PositionOffsetXYZroomsWprops;
            uniform sampler2D _Props;
            uniform float _PropsTexTiling;
            uniform sampler2D _Wall;
            uniform float _WalltexTiling;
            uniform sampler2D _Back;
            uniform float _BackWallTexTiling;
            uniform sampler2D _Floor;
            uniform float _FloorTexTiling;
            uniform sampler2D _Ceiling;
            uniform float _CeilingTexTiling;
            uniform float _RoomIntensity;
            uniform sampler2D _FacadeAlbedo;
            uniform float4 _FacadeAlbedo_ST;
            uniform float _FacadeTiling;
            uniform sampler2D _FacadeSmoothness;
            uniform float _SmoothnessValue;

            void vertexDataFunc( inout appdata_full v, out Input o )
            {
                UNITY_INITIALIZE_OUTPUT( Input, o );
                float3 ase_vertex3Pos = v.vertex.xyz;
                o.data447 = ase_vertex3Pos;
            }

            void surf( Input i , inout SurfaceOutputStandard o )
            {
                float4 temp_output_174_0 = ( ( _RoomsXYZPropsW + float4( -1E-05,-1E-05,-1E-05,-1E-05 ) ) * _RoomTile );
                #ifdef _SWITCHPLANE_ON
                    float staticSwitch479 = (i.data447).z;
                #else
                    float staticSwitch479 = (i.data447).x;
                #endif
                float4 appendResult465 = (float4(i.data447 , staticSwitch479));
                float4 InterpVertexPos448 = appendResult465;
                float4 temp_output_46_0 = ( InterpVertexPos448 - _PositionOffsetXYZroomsWprops );
                float4 appendResult373 = (float4(_WorldSpaceCameraPos , 1.0));
                float4 temp_output_374_0 = mul( unity_WorldToObject, appendResult373 );
                #ifdef _SWITCHPLANE_ON
                    float staticSwitch480 = (temp_output_374_0).z;
                #else
                    float staticSwitch480 = (temp_output_374_0).x;
                #endif
                float4 appendResult468 = (float4((temp_output_374_0).xyz , staticSwitch480));
                float4 TransCameraPos445 = appendResult468;
                float4 V2177 = ( TransCameraPos445 - _PositionOffsetXYZroomsWprops );
                float4 V1182 = ( temp_output_46_0 - V2177 );
                float4 temp_output_59_0 = ( ( ( ( floor( ( temp_output_174_0 * temp_output_46_0 ) ) + step( float4( 0.0,0,0,0 ) , V1182 ) ) / temp_output_174_0 ) - V2177 ) / V1182 );
                float Y189 = (temp_output_59_0).y;
                float newPlane383 = (temp_output_59_0).w;
                float Z190 = (temp_output_59_0).z;
                float4 temp_output_389_0 = ( ( newPlane383 * V1182 ) + V2177 );
                #ifdef _SWITCHPLANE_ON
                    float2 staticSwitch482 = (temp_output_389_0).xy;
                #else
                    float2 staticSwitch482 = (temp_output_389_0).yz;
                #endif
                float2 appendResult396 = (float2(( staticSwitch482 * _PropsTexTiling ).x , ( staticSwitch482 * _PropsTexTiling ).y));
                float2 appendResult546 = (float2(( staticSwitch482 * _PropsTexTiling ).y , ( staticSwitch482 * _PropsTexTiling ).x));
                #ifdef _SWITCHPLANE_ON
                    float2 staticSwitch490 = appendResult396;
                #else
                    float2 staticSwitch490 = appendResult546;
                #endif
                float4 tex2DNode285 = tex2Dbias( _Props, float4( staticSwitch490, 0, -1.0) );
                float4 appendResult505 = (float4(tex2DNode285.r , tex2DNode285.g , tex2DNode285.b , 0.0));
                #ifdef _TOGGLEPROPLAYER_ON
                    float4 staticSwitch502 = tex2DNode285;
                #else
                    float4 staticSwitch502 = appendResult505;
                #endif
                float4 PropsVar428 = staticSwitch502;
                float temp_output_300_0 = step( newPlane383 , ( Z190 * (PropsVar428).a ) );
                float ifLocalVar416 = 0;
                if( temp_output_300_0 <= 0.0 )
                    ifLocalVar416 = Z190;
                else
                    ifLocalVar416 = newPlane383;
                float X188 = (temp_output_59_0).x;
                float temp_output_402_0 = step( ifLocalVar416 , X188 );
                float ifLocalVar422 = 0;
                if( temp_output_402_0 <= 0.0 )
                    ifLocalVar422 = X188;
                else
                    ifLocalVar422 = ifLocalVar416;
                float2 appendResult147 = (float2(( (( ( Z190 * V1182 ) + V2177 )).xy * _WalltexTiling ).x , ( (( ( Z190 * V1182 ) + V2177 )).xy * _WalltexTiling ).y));
                float4 WallVar426 = tex2D( _Wall, appendResult147 );
                float4 ifLocalVar407 = 0;
                if( temp_output_300_0 <= 0.0 )
                    ifLocalVar407 = WallVar426;
                else
                    ifLocalVar407 = PropsVar428;
                float4 BackVar430 = tex2D( _Back, ( (( ( X188 * V1182 ) + V2177 )).zy * _BackWallTexTiling ) );
                float4 ifLocalVar408 = 0;
                if( temp_output_402_0 <= 0.0 )
                    ifLocalVar408 = BackVar430;
                else
                    ifLocalVar408 = ifLocalVar407;
                float2 temp_output_79_0 = (( ( Y189 * V1182 ) + V2177 )).xz;
                float Y_inverted191 = (V1182).y;
                float4 lerpResult435 = lerp( tex2D( _Floor, ( temp_output_79_0 * _FloorTexTiling ) ) , tex2D( _Ceiling, ( temp_output_79_0 * _CeilingTexTiling ) ) , step( 0.0 , Y_inverted191 ));
                float4 CeilVar432 = lerpResult435;
                float4 ifLocalVar423 = 0;
                if( Y189 <= ifLocalVar422 )
                    ifLocalVar423 = CeilVar432;
                else
                    ifLocalVar423 = ifLocalVar408;
                float4 temp_output_540_0 = ( _RoomColorTint * ( ifLocalVar423 * _RoomIntensity ) );
                float2 uv_FacadeAlbedo = i.uv_texcoord * _FacadeAlbedo_ST.xy + _FacadeAlbedo_ST.zw;
                float2 uv1544 = ( uv_FacadeAlbedo * _FacadeTiling );
                float4 tex2DNode1 = tex2D( _FacadeAlbedo, uv1544 );
                float4 lerpResult2 = lerp( temp_output_540_0 , tex2DNode1 , tex2DNode1.a);
                #ifdef _FACADETEXTURE_ON
                    float4 staticSwitch523 = lerpResult2;
                #else
                    float4 staticSwitch523 = temp_output_540_0;
                #endif
                o.Albedo = staticSwitch523.rgb;
                #ifdef _FACADETEXTURE_ON
                    float staticSwitch542 = ( tex2D( _FacadeSmoothness, uv1544 ).r * _SmoothnessValue );
                #else
                    float staticSwitch542 = 0.0;
                #endif
                o.Smoothness = staticSwitch542;
                o.Alpha = 1;
            }

            ENDCG
        }
        Fallback "Diffuse"
        CustomEditor "ASEFakeInspector"
    }
    /*ASEBEGIN
    Version=13502
    7;29;1906;1004;5938.686;1964.985;6.054256;True;False
    Node;AmplifyShaderEditor.CommentaryNode;453;-4305.528,2324.286;Float;False;1682.485;471.1538;Comment;11;445;468;376;480;467;481;374;372;373;370;371;;1,1,1,1;0;0
    ...

    ASEEND*/
    //CHKSM=B1726B676DA2F4F76BCD88711F1DAB60D08AAE43
```

---

As @DMGregory pointed, I can take the cross product of the window's normal with the up vector `(0, 1, 0)`, normalize it, and then multiply that by uv x coordinate. UV map for the window 'fills' the face area, i.e. if you have some texture, left upper corner of it will be in left upper corner of the face and right bottom corner will be left bottom corner of the face.

So, the only change I made in the code above is replaced

```
o.data447 = ase_vertex3Pos;
```

with

```
o.data447 = normalize(cross(v.normal, float3(0, 1, 0))) * o.uv_texcoord.x;
```

But the result is totally wrong - it a bit flickering from something darker to something lighter, when I move the camera, but it completely unreadble image:
[image]

---

UV unwrap of the face:

[image]

Also, adding `o.data447.y = o.uv_texcoord.y;` right after `o.data447 = normalize(cross(v.normal, float3(0, 1, 0))) * o.uv_texcoord.x;` seems does not change anything.

Comment: The interior mapping here is being applied in object space (the coordinate system of the building model as a whole), not world space. If you don't have one constant alignment grid for all your windows over the whole object, then you're going to need a different approach. This could include adding texture coordinates or vertex colours to each window quad to tell it where its four corners are aligned relative to its room / its place in the room grid. Then you'd use those coordinates instead of `float3 ase_vertex3Pos = v.vertex.xyz;` in `vertexDataFunc()`.

Comment: It looks like the next thing you'll need to do is adjust your eye/viewing vector to be relative to your new constructed window coordinates. For that, it will help if your UVs match the world space width and height of the window, rather than unwrapping all windows to full squares. You can use a second set of UV coordinates for this, or, if all your windows are the same size, use a uniform variable to scale them for this purpose.